# Pharo promises:

Tags: promise, smalltalk, pharo

I worked on a promises project earlier this year in Pharo Smalltalk.
The idea was to achieve the behavior below:

```
([ 30 seconds wait. 4 ]promiseValue )then: [ :a| Transcript crShow: a ].
```

This means that the promise will wait in the background for 30 seconds and print on the Transcript. This should not result in freezing of the Pharo user interface. 
My implementation below freezes the user interface. Why?

**Class promise that implements Promises behavior:**

```
Object subclass: #Promise
    instanceVariableNames: 'promiseValue promiseError promiseLock'
    classVariableNames: ''
    package: 'META-Project-[pgakuo]'
```

**Methods inside class Promise**

```
doesNotUnderstand: aMessage 
    ^ self value 
        perform: aMessage selector
        withArguments: aMessage arguments

then: aBlock
    promiseLock isSignaled
        ifTrue: [ ^ self ].
    promiseLock wait.
    promiseError
        ifNotNil: [ promiseError
                privHandlerContext: thisContext;
                signal ].
    aBlock value: promiseValue.
    self value: aBlock

then: aBlock catch: anotherBlock
    promiseLock isSignaled
        ifFalse:
            [ promiseLock wait.
            promiseError ifNotNil: [ anotherBlock value: promiseError ].
            promiseValue ifNotNil: [  aBlock value: promiseValue. self value: aBlock  ]] 

value
    promiseLock  isSignaled ifFalse: [ promiseLock  wait ].
    promiseError  ifNotNil: 
        [ promiseError 
            privHandlerContext: thisContext;
            signal ].
    ^promiseValue 

value: aBlock 
    promiseLock := Semaphore new.
[
  [[promiseValue := aBlock value] 
    on: Error do: [:err | promiseError := err]]
    ensure: [promiseLock signal]] fork
```

**And one method added to Blockclosure to make closures use the Promise behavior.**

```
promiseValue
    ^ Promise  new value: self
```

A block is passed to an instance of Promise and it is executed by Promise>>value: which uses fork to perform tasks in the background. But it does not seem to be working as desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the freezing problem as follows:

```
then: aBlock
    promiseLock isSignaled
        ifFalse:
            [ promiseLock wait.         
            promiseValue ifNotNil: [  aBlock value: promiseValue ]] fork.
```

And the below code on playground does not freeze the UI

```
[ 12 seconds wait. 12 ]promiseValue then: [ :a|  Transcript crShow: a/2 ]
```

it prints 6 after 12 seconds of not freezing the UI

Comment: This solution  leads me to a further question as to how the futures can be pipelined: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 3):

When working in a playground you'll be working within the UI process. Hence, you are effectively suspending the UI process with your example. Try this:

```
[ ([ 30 seconds wait. 4 ] promiseValue) then: [ :a |
    Transcript crShow: a ] ] forkAt: Processor userBackgroundPriority.
```

### Edit

As the there's the explicit requirement for the original expression to not lock the UI, what you should do is:

1. do not override `#doesNotUnderstand:`
2. you have a choice:

   1. always fork when evaluating a promise

      This will incur an overhead due to process scheduling and process creation. You will also lose the context of the original process, unless you explicitly save it (costs memory, incurs performance penalty)
   2. only fork if the current process is the UI process

      Checking whether the current process is the UI process is simple and fast. It's not something you would typically do but for your case I'd recommend this approach.
3. I recommend implementing a class side method for `Promise`, e.g. `Promise class>>value:`. This will allow you to isolate this specific case from the rest of your implementation. e.g.

   ```
   value: aBlock
   | instance |
   instance := self new.
   self isUIProcess
       ifTrue: [ [ instance value: aBlock ] forkAt: Processor userBackgroundPriority ]
       ifFalse: [ instance value: aBlock ].
   ^ instance
   ```

Comment: That would work but then my promise class will be letting the playground do its job. I would like that to happen solely from the promise class. I had tried to do that in the then: and then: catch: methods but adding a fork in those methods caused the transcript to show: message sent but not implemented. This might mean that approach sent the task to a different thread from the one value: works on and the value of execution could not be retrieved.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with forking in the playground, because when you're promise is being used by an application, e.g. a web server, it will (or at least should) always run in a distinct process and not the UI process. Hence, by forking in the playground you simulate an "application process".

Comment: Just one problem mate. It was an explicit requirement that the promises work exactly as I explained.

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework... Anyway, I hope the updated answer will help you solve your problem. Heads up: my answer assumes that you know the difference between class-side and instance-side methods. If you're not sure what I'm talking about you should definitely read up on that.

Comment: I think I am looking for option 2.1 in your edit. The promise has to work the same not just for the UI. It appears I am looking for a way to return a value after forking. Because my object side method value: already uses fork.